# Inversion of recursively defined function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse, recursion

In a book I'm reading, they've defined a variable $r_i$ like this,

$$ \begin{array}{rcll}
r_0 &=&q_1r_1+r_2, & 0 < r_2 < r_1 \\
r_1 &=&q_2r_2+r_3, &  0 < r_3 < r_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
r_{m-2} &=&q_{m-1} r_{m-1}+r_m, & 0 < r_m < r_{m-1} \\
r_{m-1} &=&q_m r_m.
\end{array} $$

Afterwards they use it inverted in a proof like
$$ r_i = r_{i-2} - q_{i-1} r_{i-1} $$

I'm trying to show that,
$$ r_i = q_{i+1} r_{i+1} + r_{i+2} = r_{i-2} - q_{i-1} r_{i-1} $$
 in order to understand what's going on.

But I'm invariably stuck, coming up with all kinds of assumptions and results. One example is,

Assumption: (based on the book)
\begin{align*}
r_{i-1} &= q_{i} r_{i}, \\
r_{i-2} &= q_{i-1} r_{i-1} + r_{i}, \\
%
r_{i+1} &= r_{i-2+1} - q_{i-1+1} r_{i-1+1} = r_{i-1} - q_{i} r_{i}, \\
r_{i+2} &= r_{i-2+2} - q_{i-1+2} r_{i-1+2} = r_{i} - q_{i+1} r_{i+1},\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
0 =& q_{i+1} r_{i+1} 
    + r_{i+2} 
    - r_{i-2} 
    - q_{i-1} r_{i-1}\\
%
  =& q_{i+1} r_{i+1} 
    + (r_{i} - q_{i+1} r_{i+1}) 
    - (q_{i-1} r_{i-1} + r_{i}) 
    - q_{i-1} r_{i-1}\\
%
  =& q_{i+1} r_{i+1} 
    + r_{i} - q_{i+1} r_{i+1}
    - q_{i-1} r_{i-1} - r_{i} 
    - q_{i-1} r_{i-1}\\
  %
  =& q_{i+1} r_{i+1} 
    - q_{i+1} r_{i+1}
    - q_{i-1} r_{i-1}
    - q_{i-1} r_{i-1}\\
  %
  %
  =& 2 q_{i-1} r_{i-1} \\
  %
  =& 2 q_{i-1} ( q_{i} r_{i} ) \\
  %
  =& 2 q_{i-1} q_{i} ( q_{i+1} r_{i+1} + r_{i+2}) \\
  %
  %
  =& 2 q_{i-1} ( q_{i} r_{i} + r_{i-1} - q_{i} r_{i} ) \\
  %
  =& 2 q_{i-1} r_{i-1} \\
\end{align*}

I'm probably missing something incredibly basic, but I've been at it for two hours, so I've tried. I'm not even sure I'm making the right assumptions anymore, given that the above yields something like $$r_{i+1} = r_{i-1} - q_{i} r_{i} = q_{i} r_{i} - q_{i} r_{i} = 0$$
So any help is appreciated.

[edit]
Another attempt, based on the assumption: $ r_{i-1} = q_{i} r_{i} + r_{i+1} $

\begin{align}
0 =& q_{i+1} r_{i+1} 
    + r_{i+2} 
    - r_{i-2} 
    - q_{i-1} r_{i-1}\\
%
  =& q_{i+1} (r_{i-1} - q_{i} r_{i}) 
    + (r_{i} - q_{i+1} r_{i+1}) 
    - (q_{i-1} r_{i-1} + r_{i}) 
    - q_{i-1} (q_{i} r_{i} + r_{i+1})\\
  %
  =& q_{i+1} r_{i-1} - q_{i+1} q_{i} r_{i} 
    + r_{i} - q_{i+1} r_{i+1}
    - q_{i-1} r_{i-1} - r_{i}
    - q_{i-1} q_{i} r_{i} - q_{i-1} r_{i+1}\\
  %
  =& q_{i+1} r_{i-1} - q_{i+1} q_{i} r_{i} 
    - q_{i+1} r_{i+1}
    - q_{i-1} r_{i-1} 
    - q_{i-1} q_{i} r_{i} - q_{i-1} r_{i+1} - r_{i} + r_{i}\\
    %
  =& q_{i+1} r_{i-1} - q_{i+1} q_{i} r_{i} 
    - q_{i+1} r_{i+1}
    - q_{i-1} r_{i-1} 
    - q_{i-1} q_{i} r_{i} - q_{i-1} r_{i+1}\\
    %
  =& q_{i+1} (r_{i-1} - q_{i} r_{i} - r_{i+1})
    - q_{i-1} (r_{i-1} + q_{i} r_{i} + r_{i+1})\\
    %
    %
  =& q_{i+1} (r_{i+1} - r_{i+1})
    - q_{i-1} (r_{i-1} + r_{i-1})\\
    %
  =& - q_{i-1} (r_{i-1} + r_{i-1})\\
    %
    %
    &\\
    &\\
\end{align}

I just don't seem to get anywhere.

[Edit 2, solution] Move $- q_{i-1} r_{i-1}$ over, increment subscripts twice.
\begin{align*}
    r_i &= r_{i-2} - q_{i-1} r_{i-1} \Rightarrow\\
    %
    r_{i-2} &= r_{i} + q_{i-1} r_{i-1} \Rightarrow\\
    %
r_{i-1} &=  r_{i + 1} + q_{i} r_{i} \Rightarrow\\
    %
 r_{i} &= r_{i + 2} + q_{i+1} r_{i+1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Hint: $\;r_i = r_{i-2} - q_{i-1} r_{i-1} \iff r_{i-2} = q_{i-1} r_{i-1} + r_i\,$. Now replace $i \mapsto i+2\,$.

Comment: You have just saved my sanity.

Comment: I'm unsure how to proceed from here. Do I post the answer? Deep-six my question? Do nothing?

Comment: It's perfectly OK to post an answer to your own question.